# How to set background color of treeview widget in Gtk using C

Tags: gtk

I would like to set background color of treeview widget through xml like this becoz even-row-color and odd-row-color are style property of treeview widget.When I apply this my all the widgets available on window will be disappear. can anybody tell me the solution for this problem.

True
 White
 gray

Answer (score -1):

You should write gtk rc file to set the colors of the widgets.
here is the link on how to write gtk rc files.
http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-GTKRcFileFormat.html

After writing rc file you should parse this file in the beginning of your program(before display GUI). 
http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-GtkRcFiles.html